# Delphi TRibbon only loads after moving window

Tags: delphi, ribbon, delphi-xe7

I am creating a TControl application with a TRibbon for my job.  I've created a ribbon before with no problems, but this one seems to be acting strange.  I have dropped a TRibbon on to my form from the Tool Palette with four pages.  There is no written code associated with the ribbon yet, but when I run the program, the ribbon will not appear until I move the entire window.  The ribbon controls will also not refresh until the window is moved.  Is there some setting or event that I am not aware of?

When the form is created, there appears to be a hole in the form where the ribbon should be until the window is moved and the ribbon appears.

Comment: The Emba ribbon control is notoriously poor. You'd be better with another. The MS platform control works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with linking between units and components.  I was trying to test the program before I put my data module in the uses list.  This was causing the interpreter to freak out and load incorrectly.